# Pagination working locally but not on live site

Tags: posts, pagination

I have a loop on my single.php page like this:-

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; ?>     
    <?php $this_post = $post->ID; query_posts( array('meta_key' => 'epicredrank', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'paged' => $paged, 'category__in' =>  wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID ), 'post__not_in' => array($this_post),  ) ); ?>




    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>




    <?php if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) { 
                get_template_part( 'video-post' );
            } elseif ( has_post_format( 'image' )) {
                get_template_part( 'image-post' );
            } else {
               get_template_part( 'standard-post' );
            }

        ?>


    <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

This works on my local installation to paginate posts on single.php but not on the live server and I can't work out why.

Have tried saving permalinks etc...

EDIT:-

If I use the permalink structure 'default' it works just fine, but it fails on pretty permalinks.

Comment: What fails on the live install. Any debugging errors? BTW, don't use `query_posts`, never. Please go and read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/31545) Rewrite your code useing `WP_Query`

Comment: No debugging errors, but pagination fails. I'm using query_posts for specific reasons.

Comment: because pre_get_posts doesn't work on single.php

Comment: `paged` is the query var for paginated archives, single posts use `page`.